# Long time behavior for $u''(t) + u'(t) = \sin u(t) ,\ u(0)=1,\ u'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I prove it?

$\textbf{Problem.}$ $u(t)$ is solution of the following initial value problem.
$$\begin{cases} u''(t) + u'(t) = \sin u(t) &\;\;(t>0),\\ u(0)=1,\;\; u'(0)=0 & \end{cases}$$
(1) Show that $u(t)$ and $u'(t)$ are bounded on $t>0$.

(2) Find $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} u(t)$ with proof.

Resource:  2017 South Korea USCM P8.

My approach to solving the problem is to try to use the Laplace transform.
$$
\mathcal{L}\{u''(t)\}+\mathcal\{u'(t)\}-\mathcal{L}\{\sin(u(t))\}=0$$
$$\left[s^{2}U(s)-su(0)-u'(0)\right]+\left[sU(s)-u(0)\right]-\mathcal{L}\{\sin(u(t))\}=0
$$
Now, using (IV) we can find that
$$\left[s^{2}U(s)-s\right]+\left[sU(s)-1\right]-\mathcal{L}\{\sin(u(t))\}=0$$

but I don't know how to continue from there.

Comment: We can get the bound $|u'(t)| \leq 1$, since $u'(b)>1$ would imply a interval $(a,b)$ where $u''(t)<0$ in the interval but $u'(a) = 1 < u'(b)$.

Comment: uhm. I don't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [solving a particular form of Chini's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791761/solving-a-particular-form-of-chinis-equation)